# Show that $\frac{1+|z|^2}{1+|\gamma(z)|^2}|\gamma'(z)|$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma(z)$ be möbius tranformation i.e. $\gamma(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \quad (ad-bc \neq 0).$ Show that $$\frac{1+|z|^2}{1+|\gamma(z)|^2}|\gamma'(z)|$$ is bounded.

I tried expanding it and it became such a mess that I think there must be a pretty easy way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
f(z)=\frac{1+|z|^2}{1+|\gamma(z)|^2}|\gamma'(z)|.
$$
Then for every $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{-b/a,-d/c\}$ we have
$$
f(z)=\frac{1+|z|^2}{1+|\gamma(z)|^2}\cdot\left|\frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2}\right|=|ad-bc|\cdot\frac{1+|z|^2}{|cz+d|^2+|az+b|^2}
$$
Since $\Delta:=ad-bc\ne 0$, we can't simultaneously have $az+b=0$ and $cz+d=0$. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{z\to-b/a}f(z)&=&|\Delta|\cdot\frac{1+|b/a|}{|d-bc/a|^2}=\frac{|a|^2+|ab|}{|\Delta|},\\
\lim_{z\to-d/c}f(z)&=&|\Delta|\cdot\frac{1+|d/c|}{|ad/c-b|^2}=\frac{|c|^2+|cd|}{|\Delta|},
\end{eqnarray}
i.e. $f$ has no singularities at $-b/a$ and at $-d/c$.

Since
$$
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}f(z)=\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{|\Delta|(1+|z|^{-2})}{|a+bz^{-1}|^2+|c+dz^{-1}|^2}=\frac{|\Delta|}{|a|^2+|c|^2}
$$
we deduce that $f$ is bounded outside a disk $D_R:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: \, |z|\le R\}$, and by continuity, $f$ is bounded in $D_R$. Hence $f$ is bounded.